# Visualization of graph on client side

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I have one question about visualization on JavaScript. I read a lot of questions and articles but i have more specific needs

1) custom renderer - abbility to write a node by myself

2) draw an oriented graph (with arrows)

3) optional, ability to highlight a cycle or highlight edge

4) ability to add edge manualy by mouse

Is any JS library which realize such functionality?

Comment: You say you have one question... but you don't say what that question is.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, add question to the main question

Comment: [http://d3js.org/](http://d3js.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the drag-node chart from PowerCharts @ http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#drag-node-chart